# Zscore across dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I calculate the zscore for each row in a dataframe? Below shows an example of what I want, with the zscore being calculated for each date.

```
Original df:
                       A         B         C         D         E  
    2020-06-30     -0.066    -0.191    -0.120     0.452     -0.074   
    2020-07-31     -0.058    -0.265    -0.109     0.500     -0.068   
    2020-08-31      0.115    -0.187    -0.017     0.627      0.068   
 
  

Zscore df:
                       A         B         C         D         E   
    2020-06-30     -0.256    -0.743    -0.468      1.755     -0.289   
    2020-07-31     -0.199    -0.909    -0.373      1.715     -0.234   
    2020-08-31     -0.218    -0.884    -0.375      1.723     -0.246
```

Comment: can you try with scipy.zscore

Answer (score 0):

Use `scipy.stats.zscore` with `apply`:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
df.apply(zscore, axis=1)
```

The zscore df is not matching if you apply above code.